# Is there an standard benchmark for webAssembly?

Tags: c++, testing, benchmarking, webassembly

Is there any standard benchmark test for webAssembly or program langauage?

I want to migrate my c++ program to webAssembly ，so i must do some benchmark to test the preformence of webAssembly and compared it with c++ preformence.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. But there has been strong agreement on the Wasm CG to create a comprehensive benchmark suite, see the [notes from the last F2F meeting](https://github.com/WebAssembly/meetings/blob/master/2019/CG-06.md#collaborative-benchmark-suite--hr) and the linked slides. A GH [repository](https://github.com/WebAssembly/benchmarks) has been created for it recently, but it only contains general information so far.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE (Post Investigation @ Webassembly SF)**

After attending the Webassembly Meetup and asking for a variety of peoples opinions. I was lucky enough to stumble across some people who had thought about this VERY thoroughly.

1. Only use Fib Seq if you're just wanting to compare the first run of Javascript (pre JIT Optimizations) against wasm speed. This is more useful to see if an update to the browser's guts or a change in a machine has a significant effect. HOWEVER: it is a Microbenchmark, and so it isn't going to give you a full view of all the different types of speeds there are. (One language isn't always x amount faster than another in EVERY type of operation). TLDR: other people have already written this out (no need to write it yourself). This should only be looked at along with a suite of other benchmarking functions, unless your program is specifically fib seq. :D.
2. **WHAT YOU REALLY WANT TO DO: Microbenchmark for your most expensive operations in your existing application.** It really depends on what application you are wanting to execute. The best option for you would probably be to profile your existing c++ application in runtime to see what operations are taking up the most time. Then, create some sort of bulk unit test for JUST those "expensive" operations. Say it is the manipulation of an image's pixels: create a test that plugs 100 pictures through and calculates the average execution time. Then focus on recreating that specific "bulk" test in .wasm to see what performance changes you will experience. This can help you decide if you want to migrate / be able to predict the speed impacts of the migration.
3. One person who shed a light on this last night was Aaron Turner, who has a wonderful related article related to benchmarking wasm, Here is his article since I don't want to speak for him: https://medium.com/@torch2424/webassembly-is-fast-a-real-world-benchmark-of-webassembly-vs-es6-d85a23f8e193

---

**ORIGINAL**

I've been using **Fibonacci Sequence to 25** for my benchmarks.

**Why Do I?:**

- Even though it is computationally expensive, it is super easy to program in many languages without needing to involve a bunch of imported libraries (vs crypto bench marking)
- has some real world use.
- Seems like others have done so... (When in doubt, sheep it out) https://boyan.io/angular-wasm/fibonacci << even shows the JS comparison!

However, I would still consider what you're using webassembly for.
If you're trying to include c++ functionality on a front end website... then wouldn't you be wanting to test the speed of Javascript against Webassembly (Since a "native" C++ program isn't supported on the browser and thus cannot be benchmarked in said conditions?). I do know that web-assembly can be used outside the browser and if that is your case (say an IoT sensor) I'll take my previous assertion back.

For the vast majority of people who may read this though... they would probably be in the head-space of "webassembly for a web-application" < In which case benchmarking js vs wasm would shine light on how much performance you're introducing to your web-application with wasm.

**PLEASE** Correct me if I'm wrong in my assumptions or statements. Also if the powers that be have a suggested standardized benchmark, LMK! I'm interested to hear from someone who has more experience in web-assembly!

**PS**: I'll be attending the SF Webassembly Meeting tonight and will propose this question to the big wigs there!

Comment: Micro benchmarks are not usually a good way to measure general performance, let alone a single one.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: and especially not *this* microbenchmark: it's either testing extended precision, or it's testing a single dependency chain of integer `add` operations (and/or loop overhead).  Or I guess for the recursive case, testing the optimizer's ability to turn braindead O(Fib(n)) code back into an O(n) loop; looks like both fail.  It's at least an interesting microbenchmark, but yeah tells us very little about the big picture and nothing to auto-vectorize with SIMD or anything like that.

Comment: @Peter-Cordes & Andreas Rossberg

Updated, but still interested to hear your views on the above, thanks for the comments!

Comment: That's an improvement.  You might want to clarify that "expensive operation" has to be something big enough to be realistic, not just something on a single pixel.  (Not so small that however wasm -> native machine code JITs it, execution will overlap a lot with surrounding code so context will matter a lot.)  Also, some code might bottneck on cache misses, so just generating 100 images up front might mean they're cold in cache.

Comment: You don't always have to write wasm by hand; clang/LLVM can compile to wasm (instead of machine code or asm for a hardware ISA).  https://godbolt.org/z/JUxC_v